# Get an array of id with the selector being a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one modal with several `checkbox`. These checkboxes receive a `class` when checked (marked).

I need to get all `id` that have a marked `class`. How do I do that?

I tried the code below, but I did not succeed:

```
var test = $('.marked');
var array[];

for(var i = 0; i<test.length; i++){
   array[i] = $('.marked').attr('id');
}
```

Comment: I found the examples mentioned here better when dealing with classes as selectors and getting ids in an array. The explanations of the comments from this post made more sense to this checkbox situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each()` to iterate and add them to your array:

```js
var test = $('.marked');
var arr = [];

$(test).each((idx, el) => arr.push($(el).attr('id')));

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marked" id="1"></div>
<div class="marked" id="2"></div>
<div class="notmarked" id="3"></div>
```

Even easier yet, you can just use the internal [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/#callback) function, and use [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/#callback) to convert it to a nice array:

```js
var arr = $('.marked').map((idx, el) => $(el).attr('id')).get();

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marked" id="1"></div>
<div class="marked" id="2"></div>
<div class="notmarked" id="3"></div>
```

Comment: I got it that way and I found the last tip better. Thank you!

Comment: I using this way, will I have problems with other browsers? Is it compatible with all? Where can I get this information?

Comment: @AndrewMarques You can find browser compatibility tables for methods on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility

Comment: How can I mount an array with properties and for each array property use .map?
I tried this way but I could not:

`var array = [
 'key': $('.checked').map((idx, el) => $(el).parent().find('span').attr('class').replace('nome_grupo_comercial_').text()).get(),
 'value': $('.checked').map((idx, el) => $(el).parent().find('span').text()).get()
];`

Comment: Array's don't have keys; they only have values. Maybe you're thinking of an object: `{key: value}` @AndrewMarques?

Comment: Yes, something exactly with key and value. But using .map to get the id according to class. @FrankerZ

Comment: @AndrewMarques `var arr = $('.marked').map((idx, el) => ({key: $(el).attr('id'), value: el})).get();`

Comment: Thanks again for the help. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = $('.marked');
console.log( test.map((index, element) => element.id).get() );
```

Use `map()` to get all the ids, and then use `get()` to turn it into a simple array.

Comment: I understood that and I thought it was better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()`:

```js
var ids = $(".marked").map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get();
console.log(ids.join(","))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' checked class='marked' id='m1' />
<input type='checkbox' checked class='marked' id='m2' />
<input type='checkbox' id='m3' />
<input type='checkbox' id='m4' />
<input type='checkbox' checked class='marked' id='m5' />
```

Comment: I understood that and I thought it was better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use plain javascript:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("marked");
var arr = [];
for(el of elements) {
    if(el.id) { //make sure the element has an id
    arr.push(el.id);
  }
}
```

You could also use Array.map with a little trickery:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("marked");
var arr = Array.prototype.map.call(elements, function(el){
    if(el.id) return el.id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a css selector and wrap it in `Array.from` to cast it from a `NodeList` to an actual array. Then you can call `map` on that array to create a new array containing the element `id` for each:

```js
var markedElementIds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div[class='marked']")).map(el => el.id)
console.log(markedElementIds);
```

```html
<div class="marked" id="1"></div>
<div class="marked" id="2"></div>
<div class="notmarked" id="3"></div>
<div class="marked" id="4"></div>
```